# Only take layout_weight available space if Layout can fill it

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have a horizontal LinearyLayout that I want to fill with two TextView elements. However I was them to maximize the space by minimizing the max number of lines.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <TextView
            android:text="AAAAAAAAAA AAAA AAA A"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <TextView
            android:text="BBBB BBBBBBBB BBBB"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

These strings vary in size dramatically. They each need to be pinned to the sides of the screen

[AAAAAAA    BBBBBBB]

--

[AAAAAAAisLong BBBB]

---

[AA   BBBBBBBBBBBBB]

---

(MultiLine - same number of lines)

[AAAAAAAA BBBBBBBB]

[AAAAA    BBBB    ]

---

[AAAAA BBBBBBBBBBB]

[AAA   BBBBBBBBB  ]

How do I write an xml layout that minimizes the max number of lines for both views by changing the middle point? All while maintaining the case where there is space between them. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of a simple way to do what you're asking. The only idea that I can come up with that will be both relatively simple and relatively close to what you want is to dynamically assign each view a weight based on the string length. You could probably even just use `.length()` for the weight value of each one. Obviously if one string is all "W"s and the other is all "i"s then it won't be a perfect match, but it should be close.

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) textView1.getLayoutParams();
params.weight = text1.length();
textView1.setLayoutParams(params);

params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) textView2.getLayoutParams();
params.weight = text2.length();
textView2.setLayoutParams(params);
```